# Dynamically changing rateById.set in chloropeth map

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am trying to modify Mike Bostock's chloropeth map using a jqueryslider so instead of

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment.tsv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.rate); })
    .await(ready);
```

I have

```
function refresh(p) {
        queue()
            .defer(d3.json, "us.json")
            .defer(d3.csv, "unemployment2.csv", function (d,p) {
                rateById.set(d.id, +p);    
            })
            .await(ready);
        console.log(p);
    }
```

I am capturing the value in the slider with the code below

```
$(function () {
        $("#slider").slider({
            value: 100,
            min: 2000,
            max: 2013,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#year").val(ui.value);
                refresh("+d.rate" + ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#year").val($("#slider").slider("value"));

    });
```

When I write p to the console it comes out as d.rate2013, d.rate2012, etc. as I want but the value is not going into rateById.set. I am also getting a chloropeth map where the lines gradually disappear as I advance across the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shadowing `p` by declaring it again in the function, i.e. it should be

```
.defer(d3.csv, "unemployment2.csv", function (d) {
     rateById.set(d.id, +p);    
})
```

You also want to pass in the name of the column, not the javascript code. That is, do

```
refresh("rate" + ui.value);
```

and then

```
.defer(d3.csv, "unemployment2.csv", function (d) {
     rateById.set(d.id, +d[p]);    
})
```

On a general note, there's no need to reload the data every time the slider is moved, you just need to iterate over the data and set `rateById` to the appropriate value.